# Floating + vertical alignment

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment

How to achieve this in html/css:

```
Client:                                               Sales person:
John Smith                                            Mike Anderson
```

So basically I need two inputs tiled vertically on the left side of the page and the same on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

Did you even tried something? Simply use floats and you are good to go

HTML

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

CSS

```
.left {
   float: left;
}

.right {
   float: right;
}
```

And if it's a tabular format, than better use tables instead of divs